# Project env vars (like GCP_PROJECT, CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT) are no longer set when debugging cloud run locally

Tags: google-cloud-intellij

I used to have a number of environment vars set when I tried to run my Cloud Run Dockerfile locally.

- GCP_PROJECT
- GCLOUD_PROJECT
- CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT
- GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT

They all were just the same value – my locally configured Google Cloud project.

Now they are all gone.

Am I doing something wrong with my configuration? Did something change recently?

Help!

Comment: Hey Kevin, just to clarify, are you running your app using Cloud Code for IntelliJ (https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij) or using some other method?

Comment: Cloud Code for IntelliJ it is!

Comment: As far as I know, Cloud Code never set those environment variables. I did a quick scan through the gcloud changelog too and nothing stood out (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes). Do you happen to know of a past Cloud Code release that exhibited this behavior? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8079-cloud-code/versions

Comment: Thanks for looking @Matthew – I couldn't find anything in the release notes, either. I honestly don't know if it's the Cloud Code version or some change in my configuration that caused this!

Answer (score 0):

Short-term work-around:

`minikube delete --purge --all` and run again.

Sounds like there might be a bug that Matthew will dig in on.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11109.